# fancybox undefined in afterShow click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I have the following code that I call on page load:

```
$('#postcodes-link').fancybox({
    type: 'ajax',
    minWidth: 800,
    minHeight: 400,
    afterShow: function () {
        $('table.data-table > tbody > tr').on('click', function () {
            $.fancybox.close();
        });
    }
});
```

Now this works fine to open the fancybox ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/oskxekcz/)), but when I click on the row, it doesn't close the fancybox and just throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

yet if I make the above into a jQuery function:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.setUp = function () {
        return $(this).each(function () {
            $(this).fancybox({
                type: 'ajax',
                minWidth: 800,
                minHeight: 400,
                afterShow: function () {
                    $('table.data-table > tbody > tr').on('click', function () {
                        $.fancybox.close();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and call the following in the same place as I called the top code

```
$('#postcodes-link').setUp();
```

The fancybox will now close ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4pydLywn/3/)).  My question is why does the first one not work whereas the second one does, and how can I make the first one work?  I figure it is something to do with the scope of fancybox but then I would have expected the second one not to work as it is wrapped inside a further function

Please note I have tried various version of trying to close the fancybox:

```
$.fn.fancybox.close()
jQuery.fancybox.close()
parent.$.fn.fancybox.close()
$('.fancybox-close').trigger('click') //tried this one as a dirty hack but didn't work either
```

Comment: Which browser do you use? With firefox 37.0.1 the fancybox close well with the first  jsfiddle. Maybe the html in the first jsfiddle is not complete.

Comment: I forked the fiddle and removed the .fn in the close path. it works: http://jsfiddle.net/7v8vveko/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test the first fiddle properly, this is a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oskxekcz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out what the problem was when trying to get the fiddle to replicate the error:

On the table page, I was using the jQuery data-table plugin so I included all the scripts need to load that.  As I was ajax loading the page into the modal, it meant jQuery was being loaded for a second time on the current page.  This caused the error I was seeing.

Removing the jquery script made the fancybox work as I wanted or another workaround (if you want the target page to still work if it is not opened in a modal - eg if you have other links to that page) then you will have to use a fancybox iframe instead of the fancybox ajax modal